# How do I use Auth0 roles to modify my API's behavior, rather than simply deny authorization?

Tags: express, authorization, roles, auth0

My express.js backend has an endpoint which returns a list of what data the user is authorized to view. There are Auth0 roles corresponding to which segments of this data any given user is allowed to read. A user may have any number of these roles. However, when I tried to add role-based permissions to this endpoint, I realized that the Auth0 recommended middleware `express-jwt-authz` perhaps doesn't do what I intend: it simply authorizes/rejects based on the roles in the JWT. This endpoint only requires a user's session authorization, not the user's roles.

I want the endpoint to change its responses based on which Auth0 roles are associated with a user. The only solution I can think of is adding a row to my own database (which is not connected with Auth0) where I keep track of each user by the JWT `sub` property, and manage their roles/permissions from my backend. However, this seems like it would split roles between Auth0 and my application's database, and furthermore feels one step closer to rolling my own authentication system, which I do not want right now. Is there a way I can do this with Auth0 and express.js?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by selecting "Add Permissions in the Access Token" in Auth0 in Applications > APIs > [my API] > Settings. Then I could view the permissions passed into `req.user.permissions` on my backend, and process them how I wanted there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put the role in the User session object, you can [check out this guide](https://docs.permit.io/integrations/authentication/auth0/permit-integration)
You will need to add this code

```js
function (user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = 'my_app_name';
  const assignedRoles = (context.authorization || {}).roles;

  let idTokenClaims = context.idToken || {};
  let accessTokenClaims = context.accessToken || {};

  idTokenClaims[`${namespace}/roles`] = assignedRoles;
  accessTokenClaims[`${namespace}/roles`] = assignedRoles;

  context.idToken = idTokenClaims;
  context.accessToken = accessTokenClaims;

  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

To add this go to your Auth0 rules
In this link:
[https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/[your-region]/[your-tenant-name]/rules](https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/%5Byour-region%5D/%5Byour-tenant-name%5D/rules)